# Difference between Bitcoin and omni layer

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoind, omni

I am really confused on bitcoin core and omni core. I have several doubts, regards this,

1. it is possible to use bitcoin node for omnicore.
2. can we use the bitcoin address for usdt.
3. if we can, how to get the blockchain raw transaction using json rpc.